# HTML to PDF Converter issue - Outsystems

Tags: html-to-pdf, outsystems

I am using HTML to PDF Converter in my Outsystems application, but when I open the downloaded PDF its size is zero bytes and I am not able to open the PDF too. It throws 'No registered application for this extension.'

Any hints ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at that component's official discussion topic here

[http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=7393&Topic=[[]Html-to-PDF-Converter]-Discussion](http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=7393&Topic=%5B%5B%5DHtml-to-PDF-Converter%5D-Discussion)

Halfway through the (rather lenghty) topic a few people reported the same problem. It can be due to a multitude of problems from the page having runtime content (e.g. Flash) to write access restrictions for the creation of temp files.

Miguel

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible you are missing some dlls. Remember to upload all the dlls in the zip file which you can install from here: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html